# What's the name arguments in string_to_hash_bucket_fast for?

Tags: string, tensorflow, hash, sparse-matrix

Just new to tensorflow. When checking impl for `feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket`, I found this code:

```
sparse_id_values = string_ops.string_to_hash_bucket_fast(sparse_values, 
self.hash_bucket_size, name='lookup')
```

Not sure why use `name='lookup'` here, is it related with `lookup_ops.py`? Documentation specified in `tf.string_to_hash_bucket_fast`:

> name: A name for the operation (optional).

But not quite understand, trying to go deeper in source code, found it's wrapped in go/wrapper in a interface, even can't find a detailed algo impl. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`tf.string_to_hash_bucket_fast()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/string_to_hash_bucket_fast) creates an actual op in the graph. It's called  `StringToHashBucketFast` in the native implementation, see the source code in [`tensorflow/core/kernels/string_to_hash_bucket_op.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/string_to_hash_bucket_op.cc). In particular, it has a gradient. So the name can be helpful to recognize this op in the graph, for example in tensorboard.

The name `lookup` in this place explains the meaning of `sparse_id_values`: it's a conversion of `sparse_values` to ids (hashes).

Comment: Thanks! perfect soln and make a way